# Intermittent Parameter Not Valid when calling Image.FromStream

Tags: c#, image, jpeg

We have a website that allows clients to upload their own logos for co-branding. We resize the images so they are a standard width and height. 99% of the time this works fine but occasionally we get a "System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid." error when calling the Image.FromStream method. The odd thing is that this error only happens on our Web Servers (Windows Server 2008 R2) and not our Windows 7 or 8 dev machines. If the server throws that error for a given jpg, it will always throw the error, it's not just a random file access event or something. But our dev machines never throw the error. Once we open the image in an image editor (PaintShop Pro) on our dev machines and just save it back out to the server, then the error is no longer thrown and the server can resize the image just fine. This is not a problem with code. It's like Windows Server 2008 has a problem with a specific type of jpg, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. Anyone have any ideas?

Here's the offending code.  The filePath is valid.  The file at the filePath location will open in Paint on Server 2008 and will open in Paint on my local dev machine (Windows 8).  The code works fine on my dev machine and FromStream throws an exception on Server 2008.  I would be happy to attach two image files, one that works and one that doesn't, but I don't see the option to do so here.

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    using (var image = Image.FromStream(fileStream, true, true))
    {
        //Redacted
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show code that you have done?

Comment: Try Windows Server 2012 R2?

Comment: I don't have the option of Server 2012.

Comment: It might help to have a look at one of the offending images before they are resaved and 'healed'..

Comment: A good start would be to use an image editor that's less forgiving to questionable file formats.  Like MSPaint.  Users that create image files are not typically very good at picking the correct file extension.  They don't see the difference between a jpeg and a jpeg2000 file for example.  Your web server does.